# If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $Y \subset X $, $F \subset Y$, $F$ closed in X, $Y$ dense in $X$, is it true that $int_{X}F = int_{Y}F$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space, $Y \subset X$, and $F \subset Y$, $F$ a closed subset of $X$. Is it true that $int_{X}F=int_{Y}F$?

( $int_{X}F$ and $int_{Y}F$ are, respectively, the interior of $F$ in $X$ and $Y$)

I also have that $Y$ dense in $X$, but I dont know if this hypothesis will be used to solve the problem.

For the inclusion $int_{X}F \subset int_{Y}F$, we just have to note that $int_{X}F \subset Y $, so $int_{X}F$ is open in $Y$, therefore $int_{X}F \subset int_{Y}F$. But I dont know how to do the other inclusion.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $Y=[0,1]\bigcup \{2\}$ and $F=[0,1/2]\bigcup\{2\}$.

Suppose that $Y$ is dense in $X$,  since $int_XF$ is an open subset of $X$, $int_XF\cap Y$ is an open subset of $Y$ contained in $F$, we deduce that $int_XF\subset int_YF$.

On the other side,  there exists $U$ open in $X$ such that $int_YF=Y\cap U$. $U-F$ is an open subset of $X$ since $F$ is closed. Since $Y$ is dense, if $U-F$ is not empty, it contains an element $x\in Y$. Contradiction since $U\cap Y\subset F$. We deduce that $U-F$ is empty $U\subset F$, and $U=int_YF=int_XF$.

Comment: Nice! Is there an example with $Y$ dense in $X$? Actually I also had this hypothesis, but I thought that it is unnecessary. I edited the question.